# Can't create a remote branch using GitPython on Windows 10

Tags: python, git, gitpython

This code is from tutorial and it works for Mac and Linux, but doesn't work for Windows 10.

```
folder = os.path.abspath(folder)
repo = git.Repo.init(folder)
origin = repo.create_remote('origin', repository)
origin.fetch()
repo.create_head('master', origin.refs.master)
```

But an exception is raised:

> AttributeError: 'IterableList' object has no attribute 'origin/master'

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: It seems the remote repository does not have a branch named "master". Another possible case is that your username doesn't have access to the branch "master". For example, you haven't added the ssh key of the current user to the git server.

Comment: @ElpieKay It doesn't have. That's the question. How can I create one? And why the code doesn't work only for window.